# MVT and Taylor's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, vector-analysis

It is known to us that mean value theorem does not extend to complex or vector valued functions.

As we know Taylor's theorem is the generalization of MVT. Or MVT is the first order approximation of Taylor's theorem.

Yet there exist Taylor's theorems in both vector calculus and complex analysis.

It seems to me paradox. How do I understand it with clarity? I am curious to know your points. Thanks

Comment: There are proofs to Taylor’s theorem that do not require the mean value theorem. The key is an estimate for the error term. There is in fact an exact integral form for the error term. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Comment: I got the point, thank you Deane

Comment: Can I conclude that in complex /vector -valued function cannot have Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder? Otherwise first order of Taylor's theorem will be exactly MVT, hence contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

A long comment that tries to shed some insight:

Taylor theorem is about size estimates. MVT is about transforming size estimates into surjectivity results.

In the real field, size estimates imply order estimates imply surjectivity results for continuous and related functions since connected open sets are intervals (in particular the reasoning of MVT implies that derivatives of real differentiable functions which can be quite wildly discontinuous actually, are Darboux - ie if they take two values, they take all values in between locally, so, for example, cannot have jump discontinuities)

In the complex field neither implication above is true since there is no reasonable notion of order (closest is subordination, ie range inclusion) and there are many kinds of connected open sets around.

So if we know that some real $g$ is continuous and on some small interval is bounded by some $a>0$ and takes the values $\pm a$ we know that it takes all values in between, but if $g$ is complex, continuous and bounded by $a$ in absolute value on some small disc, its image may exclude lots of values $\le |a|$ even if we know that it takes a few values with absolute value $|a|$

Comment: Thanks Conrad, I' ll need some time to understand your answer fully.